# tkinter multiple text area vertical scrolling using mouse wheel

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a text area with a line bar(the bar on the left side which show line numbers), and when I scroll with my mouse wheel it has to scroll both text area as well as line bar

[click here to view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv2YT.jpg)

Thanks for support

Comment: Please don't post your code as a picture but include it to the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

I can't open your picture but let me try to help you.

Set the Scrollbar widget's command option to the txt yview method.

```
scrollb = tk.Scrollbar(..., command=txt.yview)
```

Set the Text widget's yscrollcommand option to the Scrollbar's set method.

```
txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set
```

You need to to this to make your txt and scrollbar react to you mousewheel.

To add the line numbers to the txt maybe you could use a loop which adds the numbers to the next row everytime you do the loop.

Here is a working code with a scrollbar reacting to the mousewheel:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()

# create a Frame for the Text and Scrollbar
    txt_frm = tk.Frame(self.root, width=600, height=600)
    txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    # ensure a consistent GUI size
    txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)
    # implement stretchability
    txt_frm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    txt_frm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# create a Text widget
    self.txt = tk.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")
    self.txt.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
    self.txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

# create a Scrollbar and associate it with txt
    scrollb = tk.Scrollbar(txt_frm, command=self.txt.yview)
    scrollb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
    self.txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```